# Neo4j 4.2 graph repo save method is now ambiguous

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have just updated from Spring Data Neo4j `4.1.3` to `4.2.7`

But, I have not been able to get my project to start running again after changing the maven dependency.

I have fixed many issues as described in this tutorial: https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/09/30/upgrading-to-sdn-42.html
But I cannot figure out why this issue has emerged.

In my service > GenericService.java > `createOrUpdate`

```
...
@Override
public T createOrUpdate(T entity) {
    getRepository().save(entity, DEPTH_ENTITY_NEXT); //ERROR LINE
    if (entity instanceof Entity)
        return find(((Entity) entity).getId());
    else if (entity instanceof GraphType)
        return find(((GraphType) entity).getId());
    else 
        return find(((DataType) entity).getId());
}
...
```

The getRepository line now gives the following error:

```
The method save(T, int) is ambiguous for the type 
    GraphRepository<T>
```

simply saving the graph repo seems to be erroring.

**UPDATE**

If I just try to Maven build the project even though eclipse shows the error. It prints this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/config/Neo4jConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a problem in your dependency management.
Please see the [templates](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-sdn-ogm-issue-report-template) for examples on how to configure your project.

Also note that `GraphRepository` is deprecated and replaced by `Neo4jRepository<T, ID>`.