# How to avoid heavily changing Maven projects when new versions come out

Tags: java, maven, spring-data-neo4j

**Specific Background**

I have just switched from spring data neo4j 4.1.3 to 5.0.0 
And this issue has arisen since I changed my pom file.

Maven install fails because "cannot find symbol ... class GraphRepository"

I am newer to Java Maven projects as a whole

**Broad Question:**

If I update maven dependencies on a given project from one version of something to another and a class that I have been using heavily now gives around 100 error codes saying that whole class is now missing... how do I have this not happen.

**Specific Where I think I'm at**

I am gonna have to remove every reference to the "GraphRepository" and change it to Neo4jRepository since "Also note that GraphRepository is deprecated and replaced by Neo4jRepository" - [Neo4j 4.2 graph repo save method is now ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408159/neo4j-4-2-graph-repo-save-method-is-now-ambiguous)

But, this just doesn't seem right. Do I really have to go through an entire project and change all that code just to update?

One full line of error:
`[ERROR] /.../service/SupportModelServiceImpl.java:[10,49] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class GraphRepository
  location: package org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository`

Comment: Well ... Nowadays, many projects use [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/). And a change in the _major_ version (4 -> 5 in your case) indicates incompatible changes. That means, you have some work to do. Or simply do not update the major version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent external dependencies from introducing breaking changes.  However you could write your code so that it takes minimal effort to update external dependencies.

I have observed that in practice not much care is given to dependencies as if they are free.  Initially they are as good as free, but once you start stacking your dependencies and have transitive dependencies that conflict or you upgrade to a new version with breaking changes there comes a maintenance cost.  I have seen projects where the web of dependencies is so complex that they should be rewritten completely from scratch, if not for management not understanding the concept of technical debt, living in the illusion that maintaining an existing (bad) version of the software is cheaper than writing a new one.

The only option you have to guard against external dependencies, is to encapsulate them in one way or another.  This may involve some boiler plate code, though if this boiler plate code is minimal it may be well worth the effort.

Because I have seen projects with horrible dependencies, I have given it some thought how I could prevent such a dependency mess and made the following image:

[image: Insulating dependencies]

External code, over which you have no control is in red.  If you do not think about structuring your code, your code (in orange) will depend directly on the external code and is at risk for external changes.  You can try to write code (in green) that has no dependencies on external code.  The way you achieve this is that you define the external functionality that you need in your own interfaces.  You have then some code (in orange) that implements these interfaces and has external dependencies.  You inject the code with external dependencies through a dependency injection framework.

This approach limits the impact of external changes to only the code in orange.  However it requires more planning than directly using dependencies everywhere in your code.  And because more planning means more effort, it is often not put in practice.

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to maven, you will have this issue regardless of whatever build system you use.

but I do not understand why you would want this, a major version change (e.g 4.xx to 5.xx) means something is going to break, and you will have to make changes into your code.